# Unable to get started with a new Expo project | ERROR: Node.js v12.4.0 is no longer supported

Tags: node.js, npm, expo, react-native

while I tried to creat react-native project using expo init projectName, I'm getting an error like this please help me solve this error.

//
ERROR: Node.js v12.4.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

- > =10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
- > =12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)
- > =14.0.0  <15.0.0 (Current Release)

//
I'm using Windows OS and I'm not using nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems straightforward. You need to uninstall your current node version and then reinstall a supported version. For example, I'm using Node v14.15.1.

To uninstall Node, open the Control Panel, then under "Programs" click "Uninstall a program". Next, find your Node installation, select it, and click "Uninstall".

To get a new Node version, go to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download/install the latest recommended version. As of now, the latest recommended version is v14.15.1.